# Cannot center image when using CSS Grid System (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot seem to center the image when the width is about the size of a computer. However, the image manages to center perfectly when width is smaller than a computer screen like mobile. I have no idea why it's doing this. Please take a look at this.

https://codepen.io/danii956/pen/PKbgGJ?editors=1100

```
<div id="introImg" class="col-xs-4 text-center center-block">
   <div class="row text-center center-block">
    <img class="col-xs-12 img-responsive center-block" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8809/light-red-white-home.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="A picture of Young Jae taken in front of University of Illinois quad">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `.col-xs-12` class adds, like every other .col-* classes do, an `float: left;`, by simply adding this css to your image will fix the problem.

```
#introImg img.col-xs-12 {
    float: none;
}
```

this will make your `.center-block` class do what it does, but with the float if the image is smaller than 250px right now, it aligns to the left. with the float none it aligns in the middle.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know col classes had float left attached to them.